# Define btrfs subvolume parent?

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs

How can I create a btrfs subvolume such that it is the child of another specific subvolume? Or, how can I ensure that it will be created with parent/top level of 5, as many of my existing subvolumes are?

e.g., say I have:

```
# btrfs subvolume list -p -a -t -u /
ID      gen     parent  top level       uuid    path
--      ---     ------  ---------       ----    ----
257     80732   5       5               43d2daae-112f-ab49-931f-ddc9ba1c6ffd    <FS_TREE>/root
258     80732   5       5               01b630a4-608d-b44f-8f97-e9c371c7c759    <FS_TREE>/home
261     80731   257     257             0dbf3e8a-a9bf-2a4a-92fe-7661d48295f2    root/var/lib/machines
```

How can I create a `new_subvolume` such that it will show up as:

```
# btrfs subvolume list -p -a -t -u /
ID      gen     parent  top level       uuid    path
--      ---     ------  ---------       ----    ----
257     80732   5       5               43d2daae-112f-ab49-931f-ddc9ba1c6ffd    <FS_TREE>/root
258     80732   5       5               01b630a4-608d-b44f-8f97-e9c371c7c759    <FS_TREE>/home
261     80731   257     257             0dbf3e8a-a9bf-2a4a-92fe-7661d48295f2    root/var/lib/machines
262     80732   5       5               XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX    <FS_TREE>/new_subvolume
```

The `root` and `home` subvolumes got created somehow, I just want to duplicate how they got made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special method for doing that. To create subvolumes, just like regular files or directories, you need to have their parent mounted somewhere...

```
# mkdir /mnt/toplevel

# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/toplevel -o subvolid=5
```

...and create a child subvolume in it:

```
# btrfs subvolume create /mnt/toplevel/new_subvolume

# ls -la /mnt/toplevel
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36 Sep 10 15:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  26 Mar  1 14:18 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14 Sep 10 15:48 home/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Mar  1 14:19 new_subvolume/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 150 Feb 19 13:07 root/

# umount /mnt/toplevel
```

(Note: by default, `subvolid=5` is already the default and doesn't need to be specified. I only added it in case you've done `btrfs subvolume set-default` earlier.)

Comment: All the btrfs subvolumes are all already mounted. I tried: `mkdir /new_subvolume ; btrfs subvolume create /new_subvolume` and got: `ERROR: '/new_subvolume' exists`. So, I deleted that directory, and tried just: `btrfs subvolume create /new_subvolume ; btrfs subvolume list -p -a -t /` and I got the new subvolume created, but with its parent & top level as 257, not 5.

Comment: I see now that I missed your instruction to create a new folder just to mount my btrfs ... fs. But I wonder why I need to do that, why doesn't creating a subvolume where it's already mounted, work? Seems that is a "special method for doing that" after all.

Comment: @courtlandj: Well, of course you can create subvolumes where it's already mounted – but the problem that your desired parent subvolume _isn't_ mounted anywhere, only its children are. http://i.imgur.com/BxAlyR9.png (I can't see your system from here, but I'm guessing that only subvolumes 257 and 258 are actually mounted.)

Comment: I understand this better now, thank you. So, perhaps "special in the case of mounted at root"?